# Reading float value from string upto 6 precision

Tags: c++, string, floating-point

i have to read a flot value from string up to 6 precision , Current code is reading first 6 digits only. Thanks in Advance

```
template <class T>
bool from_string(T& t,    const std::string& s, 
                 std::ios_base& (*f)(std::ios_base&))
{
  std::istringstream iss(s);
  return !(iss >> f >> t).fail();
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  float f;
 // the third parameter of from_string() should be 
  // one of std::hex, std::dec or std::oct
  if(from_string<int>(i, std::string("ff"), std::hex))
  {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "from_string failed" << std::endl;
  }

  if(from_string<float>(f, std::string("1456.909"), std::dec))
  {
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "from_string failed" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite certain it's reading all digits. The problem appears to be in what you expect. Let's put it a bit stronger: What would you expect to happen if you read `1456.90900000000000000000000000000` in a `float`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a double, rather than a float if you want to do better than 6 digits. Your question says "6 digits of precision" and also "first 6 digits" but you're presenting input which is 7 digits.

The float can only hold 6 digits precision i.e. x.yzpqrs or xy.zpqrs or xyzpq.rs. If you're after holding 6 *decimal places* then you need to use double.

You can make it output more decimal places by using cout.precision(7) for instance, which in this case will print the right answer, even though C isn't actually storing 7 digits, just something that approximates to the right answer.